# Open JQuery accordion based on its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to get my code to close all accordions based on an event and then open a specific accordion based on it's ID. My accordions are created dynamically and could by a lot of them. My accordions look like:

```html
<div id="accordion" class="emitters head wrapper ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-sortable" role="tablist">
  <div id="Test1">
    <h3 class="accordion-header3 accordion-content-active ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"
    tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a class="accordion-expand-all" href="#"></a>Name: Test2</h3> 
    <table id="table_test1" class="table-text table-collapse ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; color: blue; display: table; height: 17px; background-color: rgba(189, 197, 205, 0.45098);"
    id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 71px">ATF</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 73px">1.1</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 107px">2.2</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 223px">7.53</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 197px">16:37:31</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 80px">37.8715</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 78px">60.8957</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 202px">21</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 180px">ACTIVE</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 145px">35.34</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 192px">0</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 125px">27793</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 136px">0.1</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 90px">35</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Test2">
    <h3 class="accordion-header3 accordion-content-active ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a class="accordion-expand-all" href="#"></a>Name: Test2</h3> 
    <table id="table_test2" class="table-text table-collapse ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; color: darkgreen; display: none; height: 17px; background-color: rgba(189, 197, 205, 0.45098);"
    id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 71px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 73px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 107px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 223px">2.78</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 197px">16:37:31</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 80px">-108.6117</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 78px">46.6017</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 202px">CDF</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 180px">ACTIVE</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 145px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 192px">0</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 125px">11</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 136px">0.1</th>
          <th class="table-text" style="width: 90px">11</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The close all part is working fine with:

```
var contentAreas = $('#accordion .table-collapse ').hide();
```

But based on an event which I can get both the div accordion ID or the table inside the accordion ID In need to open only the specific accordion.
What javascript code will give me the ref to the specific accordion so I can use:

```
.show()
```

In order to open it?

Comment: You want to do something like when clicking the 3rd div with class "show-accordion" (for example) opens the 3rd accordion?

Comment: Can you post the original HTML code ora a demo?

Comment: I think that I need first to get a reference to the specific accordion by it's ID, and then maybe get it's index, and then use :    $("#accordion").accordion("activate", index );    for instance.

Comment: mplungjan - Can I "fake" a click on the accordion? it might be a work around.

Comment: @ksup You don't have to *fake* anything if you use the widget properly. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it by:

```
 var index = $('#accordion').find('table');
    for(var j=0; j<index.length; j++){
        if(index[j].id == selected){
            $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", j);
        }
    }
```

selected is the table ID I get from the event.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a lot of accordions with a single panel. To close such jQuery UI Accordion in a proper way, you should set the [`collapsible`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-collapsible) option. For more info see [Is it possible to have only one section in jQuery UI Accordion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34629246/2333214). I suggest having single accordion with multiple panels compared to what you have.

---

That said, to open a specific accordion you can just set it's only panel (at index `0`) as active using the [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) option like:

```
$("#Test2").accordion( "option", "active", 0 );
```

To close all the accordions, you need to add a common selector like an accordion class to all of them and do:

```
$(".accordion").accordion( "option", "active", false );
```

or with your existing markup something like:

```
$("#accordion > div").accordion( "option", "active", false );
```

Comment: Only when I use the .show() or .hide() the accordions seems to be effected, when I use the option/active they seem to not be effected at all. But with show/hide I cannot get it to work by ID, only on the whole accordion.

Comment: @ksup You are not using the Accordion widget properly. You shouldn't use show/hide etc directly. Read the updated answer and the one I linked to, also the API docs then use the Accordion widgets methods.